# Is it possible to define a record and use the key as value's generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

For example, I have an enumeration type and a generic interface:

```js
type Color = "red" | "green" | "blue";
interface Item<ItemColor extends Color> {
  name: string;
  color: ItemColor;
}
```

And I want to define this:

```js
interface ColoredItemRecord {
  red: Item<"red">;
  green: Item<"green">;
  blue: Item<"blue">;
}
```

In other words, I want a `Record<Color, Item>`, but the value of each `key` should be `Item<key>`. Is there any simple way?

Comment: `{ [K in Color]: Item<K> }`

Comment: @caTS Oh, I was keeping thinking about Record and forgot the `[K in Color]`! Thanks a lot!